# PHP mysql - Get corresponding user with post

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to return a blog_post,blog_title from a MYSQL databse but I also need the user and his/her's data (in seperate array's)

The output should be like

```
array(
    'blog1' => array(
        'title' => 'this is a title',
        'post' => 'This is the blogs content',
        'user' => array(
            'username' => 'Name',
            'lastname' > 'Lastname'
        )
    ),
    'blog2' => array(
        'title' => 'this is a title',
        'post' => 'This is the blogs content',
        'user' => array(
            'username' => 'Name',
            'lastname' > 'Lastname'
        )
    )
)
```

Using mysql there is no way of doing this in one query because it will mix up the two tables.

I have tried using left_join,right_join and selecting from multiple tables like

```
SELECT * FROM blogs a, users b WHERE b.id = a.id
```

Then I have tried using a foreach and a while loop.

```
$posts = array();
$x = 0;
while(++$x < 20){
    $post = DB::query('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = '.$id.' ');
    $post['user'] = DB::query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '.$post['user_id'].' ');

    $posts[] = $post;
}
```

But this will always return the same post/user

Comment: Does the `$post` array even contain the element `$post['user_id']` have you made sure that it exist and is equal to the real value in the sql table?

Comment: ofcourse it exists, this is just a example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a  posts for a particular user it is possible to do like this (assumed you have a relation in posts table to users table by foreign key fk_user for each post):

```
$user_id = 1;
$posts = DB::query(
   'SELECT posts.*,
   users.username,
   users.lastname
   FROM posts 
   JOIN users ON users.id = posts.fk_user
   WHERE user.id = '.$user_id
);
```

In case you need just a list of posts with related user info you can act as follows:

```
$posts = DB::query(
   'SELECT posts.*, users.username, users.lastname
   FROM posts
   JOIN users ON users.id = posts.fk_user
   LIMIT 100'
); // use your limit here
```

After you have a $posts array filled you can iterate and rearrange (if you need) or just use it as is:

```
foreach( $posts as $post ) {
   // print post info here or rearrange array
   $post['user'] = [
      'username' => $post['username'],
      'lastname' => $post['lastname'],
   ];
}
```